# Android Retrofit looping request does not execute callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have an issue with android studio and the retrofit library and the way in which it processes the data.

I have a simple flow of operation I would like:

- Request single item from database on server(fetch request)
- Wait for callback to confirm it has been received by the app
- Add another request(Loop)
- Stop adding requests when all data is sent

The issue I have is my onResponse callback for my fetch result does not run until all my requests are sent. Then all the responses are errors. ( If I call a single item(1 from the database)) the call back runs fine.

How do I force it to send one request and wait until that response before sending another?

**Loop code**

```java
private void Pull_data_loop(int total_entries){
        //int current_data_point = 0;
        boolean datum_processing = false;

        for (int i = 1; i <= total_entries; i++) {

            Add_single_datam(i);//Call until all entries are fetched from the server
        }
    }
```

**Fetch code**- Not running callback need to wait for this callback before sending next request

```java
private void Add_single_datam(int id)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Id_request", Integer.toString(id));//The ID value
        Call<Fetch_result> call = retrofitInterface.executeGet_data(map);//Run the post
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Fetch_result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Fetch_result> call, Response<Fetch_result> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200)//Successful login
                {
                    D1= response.body().getD1_String();
                    D2= response.body().getD2_String();
                   

                    boolean result = BLE_DB.addData_Downloaded(D1, D2);//Add data
                    if (result == true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "data_changes: Added data correctly");
                    }
                    if (result == false) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "data_changes: did not add data correctly");
                    }//false

                } else if (response.code() == 404) {
                    Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Get data fail");//Pass information to the display
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Fetch_result> call, Throwable t) {
                Utils.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Get data error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Note:

I am using a node js server for my requests. I send the Id and it returns that Id in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a callBack instance to your `Add_single_datam` then in your retrofit response, send to that callback success.
Then in that callBack you would have iteravel `i` and you could see if you reached the end of `total_entries` added +1 in `i` and make request again, or just stop.

Answer (score 0):

use some threading solutions like RxJava or Coroutines or AsyncTask. The reason it's not following the rule is because of there are two threads on which work is getting distributed so in order to get it make it work in sync, we have to use some threading solutions mentioned above and execute this for loop on the background thread and make it like a synchronous call and get all the results and finally switch back to main thread with the results.

If you are familiar with the AsynTask.

```
 private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Int, Integer, List<Fetch_result>> {
 protected Long doInBackground(Int... total_entries) {
 List<Fetch_result> allResults = new ArrayList<Fetch_result>();
     for (int i = 1; i <= total_entries[0]; i++) {
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
       map.put("Id_request", Integer.toString(total_entries[0]));
       Fetch_result response = retrofitInterface.executeGet_data(map).execute().body(); 
       allResults.add(response);
    } 
     return allResults;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     //show progress 
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(List<Fetch_result> result) {
     //do something on main thread, in loop on result
      D1= result[0].getD1_String();
      D2= result[0].getD2_String();
      boolean result = BLE_DB.addData_Downloaded(D1, D2);//Add data
      if (result == true) {
          Log.d(TAG, "data_changes: Added data correctly");
       }
       if (result == false) {
           Log.d(TAG, "data_changes: did not add data correctly");
       }//false
 }
}
```

now call like this.

```
new FetchDataTask().execute(total_entries);
```